# how to pass a object of json to model - retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

My response of my server is like:

```
{
"succ":true,
"result":[..]
}
```

I just pass the content of my `result` to my model. I don't make a separate model for above response.

for example:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/category")
Call<List<CategoryPeramoonModel>> Category(@Field("id") String Title);


    Call<List<CategoryPeramoonModel>> call = ((App)getApplication()).getApiService().Category("0");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<CategoryPeramoonModel>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<CategoryPeramoonModel>> call, Response<List<CategoryPeramoonModel>> response) {

            Log.e("size",""+response.body().size());
            adapter.addItems(response.body());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<CategoryPeramoonModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("error sliders",t.getMessage());
        }
    });

CategoryPeramoonModel is a model of result's content. but I got an error message.
```

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a
> null object reference

Comment: response.body() is null, that's why you are getting that error. Check your api on postman, see if it returns valid response.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is you're expecting `List<CategoryPeramoonModel>` but your `API` actually returns an object. To fix this you need to create a model for the response, something like below.

```kotlin
class MyResponse(
   val succ: Boolean,
   val result: List<CategoryPeramoonModel>
)
```

and then your `API` interface should look like this

```java
Call<MyResponse> Category(@Field("id") String Title);
```